# What does this mean? <variable> == ""

Tags: python

So I'm really new to python and come across lots of examples like this:

```
fp = open( "pc_rose.txt" )
while True:
    buffer = fp.readline()
    if buffer == "":
        break
    print( buffer )
fp.close()
```

What does the following part do? If buffer is equal to what, nothing?

```
    if buffer == "":
        break
```

Comment: It's an empty string.

Comment: buffer = fp.readline() returns a string and buffer == "" check if string is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reading the file line-by-line, and finishing at the first empty line, meaning the end of the file. `break`exits the `while True;`loop

It's horrible code though; cases where you actually *need* to manually code a loop like this a pretty rare in python. More succinct/pythonic would be something like:

`for buffer in fp.readlines():
   print(buffer)`